# How to interact with NPC?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm about to create a point & click game where the user is supposed to interact with an NPC by clicking on it. I'm having trouble with the script though, how can I get started?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a collider to the NPC (if there isn't one already included), and then call the interaction using [OnMouseDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html), like this:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
    // check that it worked
    Debug.Log("Player has clicked " + gameObject.name);

    // run your interaction code here
}
```